# Look for specific values and multiply them

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet

I am using excel to calculate the cash amount for each year.

Usually I am doing it like that:

[image]

As you can see that I am currently looking up every year by hand and multypling it with `cash * amount`.

How could I implement that in excel?

I appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly what `SUMPRODUCT` was built for. You are going to test to see if a condition (or conditions) are true. If they are you are going to do some math, and then add the results as you go down your range testing those conditions:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($C$2:$C$19=G2)*($A$2:$A$19)*($B$2:$B$19))
```

Put that in `H2`. This will test if `C2:C19` is the same year as `G2`. If it's true, then it will multiple the cell in column A with the cell in Column B. It will then add each row's result that is true and give you an answer.

Comment: Btw as I see, the first condition just checks the date value, and the latter multyply it. Is this correct as I understand it?

Comment: Yep. The neat thing here is that actually all three items `(C2:C19=G2)`, `(A2:A19)`, and `(B2:B19)` all get multiplied together for each row in the range. `(C2:C19=G2)` is a Boolean expression, which means it either returns `TRUE` or `FALSE`, or stated in how excel sees the value, as `1` or `0`. So if it's `true` then you'll end up with an expression like `1*2467*9.92` which will give a non-zero answer, or if it's `false` it would look like `0*2467*9.92`, which is `0`. All of those get added up for each row at the end of processing. This is why sumproduct allows you to do multiple conditions.